# Java bulk update mongodb documents and collections from a queue object

Tags: java, mongodb

To save on bandwith and unneccessary processing time, I am wanting to perform a bulk update with non-essential mongodb queries, say every 5 mins.

I am adding non essential updates into a queue, an arraylist, and in SQL I would iterate through this and literally read in a string that says `UPDATE blah with variable data`. I am transitioning from SQL to Java.

However in Java with MongoDB as far as I can see in all documentation it requires the use of `.set()` which is a function requiring various parameters. Does Java and mongo support a method of either using a JSON string it can parse to the database, or a similar solution?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple, answering this for anybody else who encounters this:

Create a List of `Documents` like so:

`List<Document> someList = new ArrayList<>();`

Then create a document:

```
Document someDoc = new Document();
someDoc.append("key", "value");
someDoc.append("key2", "value");
someDoc.append("key3", "value");
```

Then add this to the list:

`someList.add(chatMessage);`

And simply call the `insertMany` on your collection such as: `collection.insertMany(someList);`